# Add secondary axis ggplot - line chart with two variables - one data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I used ggplot to make a like graph with two variables, but I need to add a secondary y-axis and assign it to one of the variables ("volt").

I also would like to specify the range of the secondary y-axis (upper and lower limit), as well as the breaks - as I did for the y-main-axis.

My two variables are "Sr" and "volt".

I don't want to use different dataframes and then merge the graphs.

Do any of you know how to do it?
Oh, I must add that I am an absolute beginner!

Thanks,
Pedro

```
ggplot(data = k, aes(x = Dist)) +
geom_line(aes(y = Sr), colour="blue") +
geom_line(aes(y = volt), colour = "grey") +
xlab(bquote('Distance-um')) +
ylab(bquote('Sr87Sr86')) +
geom_point(aes(y = Sr), colour="black", size=2) +
geom_point(aes(y = volt), colour="grey", size=2) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black",size=10,face="bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black",size=10,face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black",size=8, face="plain"),
    axis.text.y = element_text(colour="black",size=8, face="plain")) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill="transparent")) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, size=10, face="bold")) +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.7061), colour="black", linetype="dotted") +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.7078), colour="black", linetype="dotted") +
geom_hline(aes(yintercept=0.70467), colour="black", linetype="dotted") +
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.01, 1000), breaks=c(0, 250, 500, 750, 1000))+
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0.7039, 0.7101), breaks=c(0.7040, 0.7050, 
0.7060, 0.7070, 0.7080, 0.7090)) +
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.25,.25,.0,.0), "cm"))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot2: Create second y-axis on the right side for one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911768/ggplot2-create-second-y-axis-on-the-right-side-for-one-variable)

Comment: Sorry, but I couldn't figure out how this previous question and answer could be used to answer my question.

Comment: Any data to reproduce your plot? Please use `dput()` to copy your data. [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Any random numbers will serve, as long as dependent variables are different enough.
Dist (X) - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
Sr (Y1) - 0.704 0.705 0.706 0.707 0.708 0.704 0.705 0.706 0.707 0.708
volt (Y2) - 3 5 10 8 12 4 11 3 14 22

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like to mention that [two axis is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right).
Having said that, if you still want two axis, you have to scale one of your variables (`volt` in this case).

```
Dist<-seq(1,10)
Sr<-c(0.704, 0.705, 0.706, 0.707, 0.708, 0.704, 0.705, 0.706, 0.707, 0.708)
volt<-c(3,5,10,8,12,4,11,3,14,22)
k<-data.frame(Dist,Sr,volt)
k$volt<-k$volt/10
```

Now, fixing the data makes things easier for plotting, just `melt` your variables

```
library(reshape)

k_melt<-melt(k,id="Dist")
```

And plotting. With `sec_axis` you can create the second axis and rescale again the values

```
ggplot(k_melt, aes(x=Dist, y=value, fill=variable, colour=variable))+ 
geom_line(stat='identity', size=0.5)+ 
geom_point(stat='identity', size=2)+scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "grey")) +
scale_y_continuous("SR", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . *10, name = "Volt"))`
```

NOTE: You can add your `theme` and `geom_hline` to this code. they don't work for the simulated data I created